# Scala: Replace newline, tab and return sequences from string

Tags: scala, scalatra

I have a string of HTML that I'm copy pasting into a String object that looks something like the following:

```
val s = """<body>
   <p>This is a test</p>  <p>This is a test 2</p>
 </body"""
```

The problem here is, when I display this string as JSON within the context of a web browser, the output displays literal `\n` and `\t` characters to the tune of something like this:

```
"<body>\n <p>This is a test</p>\t <p>This is a test 2</p>\n</body>"
```

Is it possible to perhaps strip all of these escaped sequences from my strings output in Scala?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could just

```
s.filter(_ >= ' ')
```

to throw away all control characters.

If you want to omit extra whitespace at the start/end of lines also, you can instead

```
s.split('\n').map(_.trim.filter(_ >= ' ')).mkString
```

Comment: That's really great. How come the filter didn't get rid of all white space and only the control characters?

Comment: @randombits - Because I filtered (in) everything above _or equal to_ space, and the control characters are all lower in value than space.